# Getting $post object

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm developing a Wordpress plugin and I need to retrieve some page revisions. I stumbled across this function: `wp_get_post_revision($post);`, which seems to be what I need; however, I'm having a heck of a time getting a `$post` object in my PHP file to pass to that function in the first place.

Been at this for quite a while today – I'm fried. I am going to pick it back up first thing in the morning, but thought I'd see if anyone knows anything!

Comment: Could you explain the context? Is this in the loop? On a single post page? Admin page? Or completely separate from any query?

Comment: Sure, so the way I understand this, it is not in the loop. I have created a button in the admin bar that will only be visible when the user is editing a page they are the author of. The user clicks the button when they are done editing their page, and the thought is to grab the most recent page revision, create a whole new page with it, and then role back the original page to the previous revision... that way, the production page doesn't change, and the user's revisions are saved until an admin can look it over and make it live.

Comment: Hmm, looks like none of the wp_ functions work in my plugin...

Answer (score 0):

You can get a WordPress `WP_Post` object using the `get_post` function.

Read more [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post)